# Cassandra data file name convention

Tags: cassandra

Looking at the data folder, I noticed the following files for a CF. Few questions - what are each file for? what are the 1 ... 6 for? which of the 1 to 6 contains the final (all) data of the CF?

```
<cf name>-g-1-Compacted
<cf name>-g-1-Data.db
<cf name>-g-1-Filter.db
<cf name>-g-1-Index.db
<cf name>-g-1-Statistics.db

...

<cf name>-g-6-Compacted
<cf name>-g-6-Data.db
<cf name>-g-6-Filter.db
<cf name>-g-6-Index.db
<cf name>-g-6-Statistics.db
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These files are the SSTables and metadata related to the SSTables. Here is a brief description of each file (lifted from the Cassandra source: io/sstable/Component.java)

- Data.db: the base data for an sstable
- Index.db: index of the row keys with pointers to their positions in the data file
- Filter.db: serialized bloom filter for the row keys in the sstable
- Statistics.db: statistical metadata about the content of the sstable
- Bitidx.db: a bitmap secondary index: many of these may exist per sstable
- Compacted: 0-length file that is created when an sstable is ready to be deleted

SSTables with the *-Compacted are marked for deletion. These files will be cleaned up asynchronously when the JVM performs a GC or Cassandra detects that the system is low on disk space.

The number indicates the generation of an sstable (larger ones are newer). As to which one has *all* the data, under normal conditions you data can be spread out across multiple SSTables and in memory. You can use nodetool to flush a column family and then run a major compaction to generate one file that has all the data for that SSTable (assuming you don't write anything else to that column family).

Comment: It's worth noting that the `Data.db` files contain all the data in the column family. All the others can be generated from it.

Answer (score 1):

Some useful additional info on psanford answer can be found on 
[Cassandra SSTable Format Version Numbers](http://www.bajb.net/2013/03/cassandra-sstable-format-version-numbers/), where naming convention is explained in more details (it is version dependant).